# Setting up opengrok for perforce

Tags: perforce, opengrok

I am getting following error while setting up opengrok for perforce.

-- must create client to access local files.

Please suggest solutions

Answer (score 2):

A "client", also known as a "workspace", is a bit of configuration data which tells the Perforce software some information about which portions of the reposistory you wish to access, and where to store the files on your workstation's disk.

You use the 'p4 client' command to specify the client configuration data, and then it gets saved in the Perforce server.

Then you configure a tool like opengrok by telling it the name of the client that you have configured, so that when it accesses Perforce, Perforce knows the configuration to use.

Here's some background: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/01_intro.html